# A nice way to add unique constraint to existing table for Oracles DB?

Tags: sql, oracle

There is an existing table with three columns which all form the primary key.

What is the best way to add a unique column to it? Prefferably creating a sequence for it while Im at it.

Comment: Do you mean add a unique column to the primary key, or just the table?

Comment: Add a column and a unique constraint on that column. Since I cant make a foreign key constraint on another table to the first table since its primary key is composed of the three columns it has. So I want to make a unique column, so I can reference it from another table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an additional column to a table with an `ALTER TABLE`

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD( new_column_name NUMBER UNIQUE );
```

You can create a new sequence and then create a trigger that populates the new column using that sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
  BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.new_column_name := sequence_name.nextval;
END;
```

If you are using a version of Oracle prior to 11g, your trigger would need to do a `SELECT` from `DUAL` in order to populate the `:new.new_column_name` column rather than doing a direct assignment

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
  BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT sequence_name.nextval
    INTO :new.new_column_name 
    FROM dual;
END;
```

Presumably, you'd also want to initialize all the existing rows using the sequence value before you started inserting new rows

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET new_column_name = sequence_name.nextval
 WHERE new_column_name IS NULL
```

But it seems very odd to add a new sequence-generated column to an existing table with a composite primary key unless the goal was to use that new column as the primary key.  The whole point of having a sequence generated column is so that you have a stable, synthetic primary key that doesn't depend on the actual business data.  So it would seem to make much more sense to drop the existing primary key, add the new column, populate the data, declare the new column as the new primary key, and then define a unique constraint on the three columns that comprised the old primary key.

Comment: I didnt realize I could add unique to the alter table since I thought the nulls would be the same thus not unique... Thanks Justin!

Comment: Ill do as you suggested, it does seem weird to use a unique key to reference from other tables, while the primary key is for nothing.

Comment: The point about UNIQUE constraints is that they can contain NULL values.  So it is easier to add a unique column to a populated table than a primary key one (although the latter is not that tricky).

Comment: Interesting to note that: Sql Server behaves differently in this matter than oracle. Unique constraints columns contain one null only, assuming one column unique constraint. . Good post by 
Bravid shows an example with scripts. https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=374915